# How to filter a column by the last characters in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with a string similar to

| country | string_num |
| --- | --- |
| Botswana | 864-0-0 |
| Germany | 968-0-5 |
| Thailand | 684-1-0 |

I would like to filter out all the strings that end with the numbers-0-0 and get a full data set view of rest.

I have tried the following code:

```
new_df = df[df['string_num'] > '-0-0']
```

The code runs, but I still see the rows that end with `-0-0`.

What can I change on my code that will have me seeing only the string_num that are greater than `-0-0`?

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) and invert the boolean Series with `~`:

```
new_df = df[~df['string_num'].str.endswith('-0-0')]
```

or using a regex (`$` anchors the pattern to the end of the string):

```
new_df = df[~df['string_num'].str.contains('-0-0$')]
```

output:

```
    country string_num
1   Germany    968-0-5
2  Thailand    684-1-0
```